# How to manually install a pre-compiled application?

Tags: installation, homebrew, neovim

Looking at https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/. I know I can just `brew install..`, and that's what I normally do (and will probably do after writing this up). But I feel like as a developer I should be comfortable installing a program (and I'm mostly curious). So the directory structure consists of `bin`, `lib`, and `share`:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── nvim
├── lib
│   └── nvim
│       └── parser
└── share
    ├── locale
    │   ├── af
    │   ├── ca
    │   ├── cs
    │   ├── cs.cp1250
    │   ├── da
    │   ├── de
    │   ├── en_GB
    │   ├── eo
    │   ├── es
    │   ├── fi
    │   ├── fr
    │   ├── ga
    │   ├── it
    │   ├── ja
    │   ├── ja.euc-jp
    │   ├── ko.UTF-8
    │   ├── nb
    │   ├── nl
    │   ├── no
    │   ├── pl.UTF-8
    │   ├── pt_BR
    │   ├── ru
    │   ├── sk
    │   ├── sk.cp1250
    │   ├── sv
    │   ├── tr
    │   ├── uk
    │   ├── vi
    │   ├── zh_CN.UTF-8
    │   └── zh_TW.UTF-8
    ├── man
    │   └── man1
    └── nvim
```

- `bin`: I'm assuming I can just move bin/nvim to /usr/local/bin or /opt/somewhere? Is that usually all that's done?
- `lib`: What's the point of this directory if I don't need it anymore? In general, how would one know if the binary they're `mv`'ing to their `PATH` needs dynamic libraries?
- `share`: looks like a lot of useful stuff in here like man pages, which I can probably manually install, and a bunch of important neovim files.

Comment: I guess you just want to manually install neovim. If that's so, you should follow the instructions that they have in their README. They usually have rules written out in the build scripts to install all directories in their proper location.

Comment: they don't have this information. At least I can't find it in the readme on Github

Comment: They have a section in their readme to install manually:- https://github.com/neovim/neovim#install-from-source.  It also refers to the full installation page which contains installation for almost all OSs:- https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Building-Neovim